# 'invalid column name' while using the HAVING

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, having

I am using Microsoft SQL Server 2014.

The following is my query

```
SELECT type, SUM(calories) AS total_calories
FROM exercise_logs
GROUP BY type
HAVING total_calories > 150;
```

and I get the error

> Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
> Invalid column name 'total_calories'.

Can somebody point out what am I doing wrong? Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`Aggregation` is required ,  as you have no access to alias `total_calories`

```
SELECT   type,SUM(calories) AS total_calories 
FROM     exercise_logs 
GROUP BY type 
HAVING   SUM(calories) > 150;
```

Comment: so that means that i cannot use the total_calories alias? where can i use it then?

Comment: the output of the query would have a field name 'total_calories'

Comment: @Newton after the query has been executed

Comment: so that field name is only used to display the results. i cannot use it anywhere in my query?

Comment: You can use the alias in an `order by` clause. For any other uses, you'll have to put this query in a sub-query, then the outer query can use the alias.

Comment: that doesnt mean you cant use it....if you see @jarlh answer ... its the way to use it

Comment: ok. i was basically following khanacademy classes and this query appeared there. maybe they made a mistake or are using some older/other sql version

Answer (score 6):

You can also wrap the `GROUP BY` query up in a derived table:

```
select type, total_calories 
FROM (
    SELECT type, SUM(calories) AS total_calories
    FROM exercise_logs
    GROUP BY type
) AS dt
WHERE total_calories > 150
```

Comment: @mpg, amazing, it took 8 years for someone to find the missing FROM. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

The [HAVING](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms180199.aspx) clause allows you to filter based on the the results of an [aggregate function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms173454.aspx), like SUM, MIN and MAX.  You must use these functions directly, unfortunately columns aliases from the SELECT clause cannot be reused here.  This is a consequence of the [Logical Processing Order](https://destinationdata.wordpress.com/2016/01/10/the-logical-processing-order-3/).  Taken from [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189499.aspx):

> The following steps show the logical processing order, or binding
>   order, for a SELECT statement. This order determines when the objects
>   defined in one step are made available to the clauses in subsequent
>   steps. For example, if the query processor can bind to (access) the
>   tables or views defined in the FROM clause, these objects and their
>   columns are made available to all subsequent steps. Conversely,
>   because the SELECT clause is step 8, any column aliases or derived
>   columns defined in that clause cannot be referenced by preceding
>   clauses. However, they can be referenced by subsequent clauses such as
>   the ORDER BY clause. Note that the actual physical execution of the
>   statement is determined by the query processor and the order may vary
>   from this list.
>
> 1.FROM
>
> 2.ON
>
> 3.JOIN
>
> 4.WHERE
>
> 5.GROUP BY
>
> 6.WITH CUBE or WITH ROLLUP
>
> 7.HAVING
>
> 8.SELECT
>
> 9.DISTINCT
>
> 10.ORDER BY
>
> 11.TOP

Comment: Excellent explanation. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You need the aggregate function in the `HAVING`:

```
SELECT   type
,        SUM(calories) AS total_calories 
FROM     exercise_logs 
GROUP BY type 
HAVING   SUM(calories) > 150;
```